# How to render both of latex formula and image in markdown table in Github readme file?

Tags: html, github, markdown

Now I'm modifying readme file about my team's project.
I want to make table like this:
[image]
(I made it by keynote just for description)

To render this table in markdown file,
I used following script:

```
| Description       | Image          |
| ----------------- | ----------------- |
| <p> this is rabbit </p> <br> <ul><li>Rabbit is smart</li><li>Some Rabbit can understand $E=mc^2$</li></ul> | <img src="assets/img/rabbit.png"> |
```

Then、following table is rendered:
[image]

I tried a lot, and finally realized that latex formula

```
$E=mc^2$
```

makes image not to be rendered.

Image appears when upper latex phrase deleted, like below:
[image]

I want to make table like the first figure in github markdown.
How can I do this?
I googled with some keyword like "github markdown table latex formula image" but none of guys struggled with this kind of problem as I got.

Please help me~ ;)

Comment: sounds like a bug in github's markdown parser. what's the HTML it generates for the image? And have you tried using markdown `![](assets/img/rabbit.png)` instead of `<img src="assets/img/rabbit.png" />` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have already tried markdown style image generating script ( i.e. ![](assets/img/rabbit.png) ). If it just happened because of a bug in github, It sounds better to change our design plan on readme rather than keep struggling on markdown. Thank you!